# C# ошибка CS1525

Tags: c#

Делаю метод который принимает на вход строку и, если первая буква не заглавная, возвращает перевернутый вариант исходной строки.

```
class App
{
    // BEGIN (write your solution here)
    public static string ConvertString(string word)
    {
        var check = char.IsUpper(word[0]);
        if (check == false)
        {
            return Functions.StringReverse(word);
        }
        else if (word == "")
        {
            return "";
        }
        else (check == true)
        {
            return word;
        }
    }
    // END
}
```

В итоге выдаёт ошибку:

```
(16,8): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `{'
```

Что делать?

Functions.StringReverse() – переворот строки
char.IsUpper() – проверка символа на верхний регистр

Comment: `else if (...)` а не `else (...)`, будьте внимательней.

Answer (score 0):

В исправленном коде проблема не воспроизводится, однако он содержит ошибку: сначала происходит обращение к первому символу, а потом только проверка, является ли строка пустой.

Также код можно упростить при помощи тернарного оператора:

```cs
public static string ConvertString(string word)
{
    return word == "" || !char.IsUpper(word[0]) ? word : Functions.StringReverse(word);
}
```